# Azure Forms Recognizer - Saving output results SDK Python

Tags: azure-sdk-python, azure-form-recognizer

When I used the API from *Forms Recognizer*, it returned a JSON file. Now, I am using *Form Recognizer* with SDK and Python, and it returns a data type that seems to be specific from the library azure.ai.formrecognizer.

**Does anyone know how to save the data acquired from *Form Recognizer* SDK Python in a JSON file like the one received from *Form Recognzier API*?**

```
from azure.ai.formrecognizer import FormRecognizerClient
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential

client_secret_credential = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id, client_id, client_secret)
form_recognizer_client = FormRecognizerClient(endpoint, client_secret_credential)
with open(os.path.join(path, file_name), "rb") as fd:
    form = fd.read()
poller = form_recognizer_client.begin_recognize_content(form)
form_pages = poller.result()
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for your question! The Azure Form Recognizer SDK for Python provides helper methods like `to_dict` and `from_dict` on the models to facilitate converting the data type in the library to and from a dictionary. You can use the dictionary you get from the `to_dict` method directly or convert it to JSON.

For your example above, in order to get a JSON output you could do something like:

```
poller = form_recognizer_client.begin_recognize_content(form)
form_pages = poller.result()

d = [page.to_dict() for page in form_pages]
json_string = json.dumps(d)
```

I hope that answers your question, please let me know if you need more information related to the library.

Also, there's more information about our models and their methods on our documentation page [here](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/python/azure-ai-formrecognizer/3.2.0b1/index.html). You can use the dropdown to select the version of the library that you're using.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is mostly on the serialization of date fields. Try this code.

```py
from datetime import date

def serialize_complex_obj(o):
    if isinstance(o, date):
        return o.isoformat()
    elif isinstance(o, dict):
        return {k: serialize_complex_obj(v) for k, v in o.items()}
    elif isinstance(o, list):
        return [serialize_complex_obj(item) for item in o]
    return o

poller = document_analysis_client.begin_analyze_document(
    model_id=model_id,
    document=document_file
)

result = poller.result() #result from api
doc_dict = result.to_dict()

# Write the dictionary to a JSON file
with open(out_path, 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(doc_dict, json_file, default=serialize_complex_obj, indent=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, what has worked well for me was to use the jsonpickle library to serialize the AnalyzeResult object to JSON.

To do this, you would simply pass the AnalyzeResult object to the jsonpickle.encode() function:

```
import jsonpickle
analyze_result = poller.result()
json_data = jsonpickle.encode(analyze_result)

with open(output_file_path, "w") as f:
    f.write(json_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem, access the result properly you will see them.

My package version: azure-ai-formrecognizer==3.3.2

```py
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential
from azure.ai.formrecognizer import DocumentAnalysisClient

# Define keys and configurations outside of the function
endpoint = "YOUR_FORM_RECOGNIZER_ENDPOINT"
key = "YOUR_FORM_RECOGNIZER_KEY"
model_id = "YOUR_CUSTOM_BUILT_MODEL_ID"

credential = AzureKeyCredential(key)
document_analysis_client = DocumentAnalysisClient(endpoint=endpoint, credential=credential)

def analyze_document_image(image_path):
    """
    This function do the following,
    Analyzes a document image using a custom model & returns the extracted required fields as a dictionary.

    Input Parameters:
    - image_path: The file path of the image.

    Returns:
    - A dictionary containing the extracted fields and their values.
    """
    result_dict = {}
    #calling custom Form recognizer model 
    with open(image_path, "rb") as document_file:
        poller = document_analysis_client.begin_analyze_document(
            model_id=model_id, document=document_file)
        result = poller.result() #result from api
    
     # Parsing the required key and valyes
    if result.documents:
        document_fields = result.documents[0].fields
        for key, value in document_fields.items():
            result_dict[key] = value.value

    return result_dict

path_to_sample_documents = path_to_sample_documents
extracted_fields = analyze_document_image(path_to_sample_documents)
extracted_fields
```